# Random variable with infinite value

Tags: probability, random-variables

Consider random variable $X$ which distribution is defined in the following way. Variable $X$ can take any non-negative integer value and $P(X=k)=1/2^{k+2}$ for any $k>0$. Find $P(X=0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ can take any nonnegative integer value, the distribution is defined for all values in the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of $X$ other than 0.

Then, we can just do the following:

$$ P[X = 0] = 1 - P[X>0] $$

$$ = 1 - P[X=1 \ \cup \ X=2 \ \cup \ ...] $$

$$ = 1 - \sum_{k=1}^\infty P[X=k] $$

$$ = 1 - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k+2}} $$

This sum is [geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula) with initial value $\frac{1}{8}$ and common ratio $\frac{1}{2}$, so it sums to:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k+2}} = \frac{\frac{1}{8}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{4} $$

$$\Rightarrow P[X=0] = \frac{3}{4}$$